# Double primitive type is "AnyObject" however it cannot conform to protocols that require an AnyObject type

Tags: swift

Please explain why this is the case.

```swift
let double = Double(1.1)

let anyObject = double as AnyObject

print(double is AnyObject) // 'is' test is always true
```

The above code generates a warning which is in the comment on the code. It prints "true."

```swift
protocol ClassProtocol: AnyObject {
}

extension Double: ClassProtocol { // Non-class type 'Double' cannot conform to class protocol 'ClassProtocol'
}
```

However, this code above generates the error in the code comment.

Comment: I think By this ```double as AnyObject``` you are casting this so it's true. but by doing this you are trying to give class type. so by casting you will not get an error, casting maybe failed at run time. For example, you can call a person with a other person name but it's not true he can act like other

Comment: `double as AnyObject` isn't casting (which typically means "interpret as another type without copying"). It's converting. The double is copied into an AnyObject container (it used to be an NSNumber, but now I believe it's a __SwiftValue). The `is` test also checks for "can be automatically converted to." (Swift generally avoids automatic type conversions, but it has a few.) This behavior is sometimes unfortunate. It means the applying `as` to an Array may make an unexpected copy of the array.

Comment: You can see the same behavior this way: `let x = 1; print(x is Int?)`. This prints true, even though `x` is not an Optional (`Int?`). It's saying that `x` could be automatically converted to an Optional.